# Any news about a Grooveshark scope for the Music lens?

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, lenses, grooveshark

It would be fantastic to have the ability to search for and select music from my Grooveshark account right there within the Dash.

I was under the impression this scope would be created during the Ubuntu App Developer Week (Sept. 5th-9th).  It was listed in the agenda --->> http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2011/09/01/ubuntu-11-10-development-update-9/

Has anyone seen this loose in the wild yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  To install the Grooveshark lens in Unity open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-grooveshark
```

Found on http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/grooveshark-scope-for-unity-music-lens.html

"David Callé has released a Grooveshark scrope for the Unity Music lens which lets you search for music on Grooveshark from Dash. The new scope uses the free Grooveshark API and clicking on a search result opens a new tab in your default browser, playing the selected song.

According to David, there are a few known issues though, such as:

- the results open in different tabs and aren't enqueued
- results in the local collection are not deduplicated
- some searches don't display any results due to some encoding errors
- sometimes cover art isn't displayed the first time you search for something"

Thanks to Andrew and David